# What is the term/word for using/mixing words from multiple languages at the same time?

Tags: multilingualism

The word or term I have seen before. It is an older term. Not sure if it is a noun, verb, adjective or adverb. It is not the modern term "code switching".

Comment: There is no word per se. However, some people don't master any language (don't have a native language) and are said to be alingual, in that sense. And alingual is not necessarily negative at all.

Comment: The word I know is [_macaronic_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/macaronic) meaning “written in a hodgepodge mixture of two or more languages” as an adjective and “a word consisting of a mix of words of two or more languages, one of which is Latin, or a non-Latin stem with a Latin ending” as a noun.

Comment: At Yellow Sky: that is used in French but it is not used in English. But it does not answer the answer. Also, that Wiki definition refers to written language. Not spoken language.